# Trying to derive the potential energy of an ionic crystal!

Tags: potential-energy, crystals, molecules

If we consider an ionic crystal of ions $A^+$ and $B^-$. We consider N ion pairs. Now I am trying to derive the formula once by considering the number of pairs and once considering the number of ions.

2N ions:

For the ion in the i-th position, it's potential energy is the result of it interacting with all the ions apart with itself:

$$U_i=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{2N} \frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$,

where $r_{ij}=|\vec r_i-\vec r_j|$.

The total potential energy is:

$$U_{total}=\frac 1 2 \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \sum_{i=1}^{2N} \sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{2N} \frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$

Now I don't know how to bring the above formula to:

$$U_{total}=\frac 1 2 N \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \sum_{j\neq i}\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$

Here I am also confused regarding the range in the summation, we are summing over what and what is the range?

So I though, since we have N in the above formula, perhaps I can try and derive it, by considering the number of ion pairs and not ions, meaning N. This means that we consider i.e the i-th ion pair, which has a total charge of 0,+2, or -2. But for the case when the total charge of a pair is 0, than we wouldn't get any potential term, as a result of the attraction between ions of different charge, which is clearly a mistake. So what do I do?

Comment: Can all atoms be considered identical?

Comment: Identical in what sense?

Comment: Usually one assumes we have alternating positive and negative charges in the lattice, i.e. the charges alternate as $q_+,q_-,q_+,q_-,q_+...$. Is this true here? Also, what dimension is this considering?

Comment: 3D case. I only need the formula. I don't know if you can speak about alternating pos. and neg. charges in 3D but yeah

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant. The summation of this series is not a trivial matter because the sum is conditionally convergent, not absolutely convergent.

Comment: But I am not trying to derive the madelung constant, I am aware that is difficult in 3D. All I want is to derive the formula above that contains N.